# how to form a rectangular form in java?

Tags: java

this is a pattern forming in java. Anyway, the instructions is to show odd numbers from 1-9 from user input into a rectangular pattern.

This is my code so far.. Any suggestions?

```
//Library Imports
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

//Main
public class blah {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Strict run = new Strict();

        //Input
        int[][] m1 = new int[3][3];
        int[][] m2 = new int[3][3];

        System.out.print("Enter 9 numbers for List 1 / Enter 9 numbers for List 2\n");

        for (int arr1 = 0; arr1 < m1.length; arr1++) {
            for (int arr2 = 0; arr2 < m1[arr1].length; arr2++) {
                m1[arr1][arr2] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int arr1 = 0; arr1 < m2.length; arr1++) {
            for (int arr2 = 0; arr2 < m2[arr1].length; arr2++) {
                m2[arr1][arr2] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        //Displays only those values of the arrays that are odd in rectangular form (row by row for each array).
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Display odd values in a rectangular form \n ");
        run.display(m1, m2);

    }
}

class Strict {

    //5.) Displays only those values of the arrays that are odd in rectangular     form (row by row for each array).
    public static void display(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m1.length; j++) {
                if ((m1[i][j] % 2) == 1) {
                    if ((m1[i][j] / 10 == 0)) {
                        System.out.print("   " + m1[i][j] + "   ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print((m1[i][j] + "     "));
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.print("      ");
                }

                System.out.print("");
                //Statements (m1=[i][j] = m2[i][j])
            }

            System.out.print("   ");
            System.out.print("   ");
        }

    }
}
```

The output in my code is:

```
Display odd values in a rectangular form 
    1            3                  5                  7            9
```

The result should be like this. (I think I'm almost near the output..)

[image: output picture]

*********************Update***************************************
I tried to revise the for loop:

```
//5.) Displays only those values of the arrays that are odd in rectangular     form (row by row for each array).
public static void display(int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1.length; j++) {
            if ((m1[i][j] % 2) == 1) {
                if ((m1[i][j] / 10 == 0)) {
                    System.out.print("    " + m1[i][j] + "   ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print((m1[i][j] + "       "));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print("      ");
            }

            System.out.print(" ");
            //Statements (m1=[i][j] = m2[i][j])
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < m1.length; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < m1.length; l++) {
            if ((m2[k][l] % 2) == 1) {
                if ((m2[k][l] / 10 == 0)) {
                    System.out.print("    " + m2[k][l] + "   ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print((m2[k][l] + "       "));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print("      ");
            }

            System.out.print(" ");
            //Statements (m1=[i][j] = m2[i][j])
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

The current output is:

```
Display odd values in a rectangular form 
     1               3    //This line is crooked. Can't determine where
           5           
    7               9    

    1               3    
           5           
    7               9
```

******************************Program solved**********************************
Last problem solved by fixing main method

```
System.out.print("Display odd values in a rectangular form \n ");
```

into

```
System.out.print("Display odd values in a rectangular form \n");
```

The result is now:

```
Display odd values in a rectangular form 
    1               3    
           5           
    7               9    

    1               3    
           5           
    7               9
```

Comment: You should have posted that edit as an Answer. Besides you need to acknowledge those who helped in answering the question.  At least i know `@saka1029` made some impact in answering your question. `@Andrew Tobilko` may have done same. Consider the two answers and mark one as best Answer.

Comment: I apologize as I'm new here.  How do I mark the best answer? Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print `"\n"` every time when `(i + 1) % 3 == 0`. The solution as I see:

```
int[] ints = IntStream.range(1, 10).toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
    System.out.print((ints[i] % 2 == 0 ? " "  : ints[i]) + 
                     ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 ? "\n" : ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
       System.out.print("   ");
       System.out.print("   ");
```

to

```
       System.out.println();
```